# Shift date by one week in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

In an org mode buffer (not in an org-agenda buffer) I fairly often want to shift a date by one week at a time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the cursor on the timestamp, `C-c .` to active the date selection dialog (org `C-c !` if it's an inactive timestamp).  It will default to the current value of the timestamp.  Then `shift-<up>` `shift-<down>` changes the date by one week.

Comment: I swear I've tried this a whole bunch of times before and if ends up inserting another date overlapping in some weird way with the one I `C-c .`ed on.  Now it works for me and I can't get it to do the overlapping thing any more.  I don't know what I'm doing different :-/